# How to change workspace and build environment?

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ros-indigo and ubuntu 14.04. I install ros and create catkin. But now, I want to use rosbuild not catkin build. How can I do it? Should I add new package to ROS? Should I reinstall ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213554/how-to-change-workspace-and-build-environment?/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) still works with Indigo. It explains how to create a separate rosbuild workspace on top of catkin source packages.

Note that the converse, catkin on top of rosbuild, is *not* supported.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is absolutely not recommended to use `rosbuild` with `indigo`. According to the [migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#rosbuild_support) builds from source are still supported. And there is [a tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin) on how to use rosbuild with catkin.

However, as you cannot depend from a `catkin` package to a `rosbuild` package, it might limit the portability and maintainability of your packages.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-07-13**:
thanks your answer. But lsd_slam says that don't use catkin. So, I don't want to use it.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-13**:
As said, there is a tutorial on using rosbuild with catkin (see link in answer above).
However, you might have to change/backport all required dependencies to rosbuild as well.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-13**:
It's OK to use rosbuild with Indigo, so long as the limitations are understood and acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess I already recommended you to port your packages to catkin.
You will save yourself time in having your packages in catkin otherwise you will have to
port back all newer packages to rosbuild!

There is a script which might help you, for porting your packages to catkin.

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-07-13**:
thanks your answer. But lsd_slam says that don't use catkin. So, I don't want to use it.
gravatar imagejossy (just now)edit

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
It says "They don't use", if I would need this package, I would port it to catkin.

Quote:

**"We do not use catkin, however fortunately old-fashioned CMake-builds are still possible with ROS indigo."**

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-13**:
There is no " **do not use catkin** " as far as I can see. Catkin is done with CMake so I do not see any reason why not port it to catkin.